# Serialize object reference once in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using Jackson library to serialize and deserialize my objects that will be send from and to the server. Now I have one large dataset that need to be send to the client. The dataset contains different Item objects with references to different other objects. But those are mostly the same.

My dataset looks like:

- Item A

  - Object A
  - Object B
- Item B

  - Object A

Is it possible in Jackson to send Object A once and place a reference to that item in the Item A and Item B? So I can reduce the amount of data that need to be send and the amount of memory the object will be taken on the client.

Comment: Do you want to use JSON?

Comment: Yes I want to use Json for this.